# Developing a digital literacy course

Tags: course-design

I am developing a digital literacy course in Persian. Do you know where can I find a similar course or quality content in English?

Comment: This will probably be closed as a "shopping" question. But what age group are you targeting? Youngsters? Adults? Retired people?

Comment: Maybe this should be moved to the Computer Science Education StackExchange site?

Comment: Thx for your reply. I am new to this environment. Sorry for asking a wrong question. Anyway, I am developing the course for employees of a governmental organization.